# How do I add an `.order` invocation to a ActiveRecord collection that I retrieved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3.1

I am new in this world of Rails. And I cannot get my head around this problem. How to get @microposts ordered by the date the micropost was created.

This is the line

```
 @microposts = current_user.followeds.map(&:microposts).flatten
```

I only managed to order by date the 'followeds', but that is not what I am looking for. All the attempts I have made gave me errors, so I guess I am not aware of some syntax.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would add an `order` clause, as in:

```
Micropost.where(:written_by => current_user.followeds).order(:created_at)
```

The way you currently have this line structured doesn't permit that, however, since `order` is only available on ActiveRecord::Relations, and once you do `map` you no longer have a Relation available to chain on.

If that's the case, you'll want something like:

```
current_user.followeds.map(&:microposts).flatten.sort_by { |m| m.created_at }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to approach this from another angle.

How about something like this:

```
@microposts = Micropost.where(author_id: current_user.followed_ids).order(:created_at).all
```

You might of course have to exchange `author_id` for whatever foreign key you have to identify what user a `Micropost` was written by.

If you want to reverse the posts (newest first), you just write `order("created_at desc")` instead.